# How to add one column to multiple .csv files with different values

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have the following scenario: I have a folder with multiple .csv files which i eventually want to merge and remove duplicates.

The issue i am currently having is that i only want to remove the duplicates that resulted from merging the files. In other words: Some individual .csv files already have duplicate rows which i do NOT want to have removed.

In order to achieve this, i considered assigning each individual .csv file an extra column with fixed values.

The idea is that i will only remove those duplicates that have different values in [extra column]

I already figured out how to assign such a column to an individual csv-file. But i do not know how to assign such a column to multiple (maybe hundreds) of csv files in Python. I do not mind if the [extra column] values do have 1's and 2's etc instead of x's and y's

Is there a way to do this for multiple files in some sort of FOR-loop?

Thanks for any advise!

I've added my code which merges multiple .csv files but without the addition of the extra column i mentioned.

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("files")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

# combine all files in the folder
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])

#dataframe['NewColumn'] = 50 --- adds a new column "NewColumn" to an existing dataframe and fills the column with the value 50 for each row

# remove duplicates
combined_csv.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)

# export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a column which is unique for every file. You can use some integer, hash or even the filename.

The problem you have is, you need to generate and add this column before you concatenate, so this line will propably fail:

```
# combine all files in the folder
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
```

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
dfs_to_concat = []
for f in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df['file_identifier'] = [f] * len(df.index)
    dfs_to_concat.append(df)
combined_csv = pd.concat(dfs_to_concat)
```

Comment: Hi Simon, unfortunately the column gets added with delimiter ",", can you help me changing it to ";"? Because right now he new column joins the last column and does not get added.

Comment: What are we talking about here? About the `pandas` dataframe or when you export back to `csv`?

Comment: about exporting back to csv

Comment: Set the right delimiter within this line `combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')`